# How to get cumulative record per day in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a data as below.

```
|-----------|-------------|---------------|
|order_date | customer_id | product_id    |
|-----------|-------------|---------------|
|2020-01-01 | 123456      | 0001          |
|-----------|-------------|---------------|
|2020-01-02 | 123456      | 0005          |
|-----------|-------------|---------------|
|2020-01-03 |123456       | 0010          |
|-----------|-------------|---------------|
```

Then I want to count cumulatively product_id per day like this.

```
|-----------|-------------|----------------------------|
|order_date |customer_id  |count_cumulative_product_id |
|-----------|-------------|----------------------------|
|2020-01-01 |123456       |1                           |
|-----------|-------------|----------------------------|
|2020-01-02 |123456       |2                           |
|-----------|-------------|----------------------------|
|2020-01-03 |123456       |3                           |         
|-----------|-------------|----------------------------|
```

I have no idea what kind of query will solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) count_cumulative_product_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '2020-01-01' order_date, 123456 customer_id, '0001' product_id UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-01-02', 123456, '0005' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-01-03', 123456, '0010' 
)
SELECT *, 
  COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) count_cumulative_product_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY order_date
```

with result

```
Row order_date  customer_id product_id  count_cumulative_product_id  
1   2020-01-01  123456      0001        1    
2   2020-01-02  123456      0005        2    
3   2020-01-03  123456      0010        3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this possible to use for the table with a lot of rows?

Comment: sure. of course.analytical functions are quite effective

Comment: It succeeded. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about cumulative counts of `distinct` product_ids, then you can simply use a "moving window" approach:

```
select 
   order_date,
   customer_id,
   count(product_id) over (order by product_id range between unbounded preceding and current row) as cumulative_product_ids
from `dataset.table`
```

However, *if* you want cumulative count of distinct product_ids, then you can use something like:

```
select order_date, customer_id, count(distinct x) as cumulative_product_ids from ( 
   select 
      order_date, 
      customer_id, 
      array_agg(product_id) over (order by product_id range between unbounded preceding and current row) as cumulative_product_ids
from `dataset.table`
), unnest(cumulative_product_ids) as x
group by 1,2
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried this and my dataset is around 300MB but it took more than 2 hours to run.... So I had to abandon...

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem with 300megs though.